# Can I use loop to upload multiple files via multipart::post gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multipart

So I am using [Multi-part](https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post) gem to upload multi-part form data.
And I have arrays including file paths, file names and file types.

Since I want to upload multiple files, I use `.each` to loop through those arrays and try to construct some commands like

```
"file1" => UploadIO.new(File.new('/tmp/1.jpg'), 'image/jpeg', '1.jpg'),
"file2" => UploadIO.new(File.new('/tmp/2.jpg'), 'image/jpeg', '2.jpg'),
"file3" => UploadIO.new(File.new('/tmp/3.jpg'), 'image/jpeg', '3.jpg')
```

And here is my try:

```
filepath = ['/tmp/1.jpg','/tmp/2.jpg','/tmp/3.jpg']
filetype = ['image/jpeg','image/jpeg','image/jpeg']
filename = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg']

require 'net/http/post/multipart'
    url = URI.parse("https://example.com/api/send")
    req = Net::HTTP::Put::Multipart.new url.path,
        filepath.each_with_index do |(key, value),index|
            fileorder = "file" + (key+1).to_s
            lastfile = "file"+ (filepath.size).to_s 
            fileorder => UploadIO.new(File.new(value), filetype[value], filename[value]),
            if index == filepath.size - 1
                lastfile => UploadIO.new(File.new(value), filetype[value], filename[value])
            end
        end
    req.basic_auth("username", "password")
    http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")
    res = http.request(req)
```

And it will give me error msg:

> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
> fileorder => UploadIO.new(File.new(value)...
>
> syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
> ...etype[value], filename[value]),
>
> syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
>
> lastfile => UploadIO.new(File.new(value)...

Answer (score 1):

I will point you in the right direction since it will take me a while to set up everything to make your code work.

First you have a syntax error so I would recommend you install a plugin/extension for your editor that checks the syntax for your code when you save the file. (I know from experience that your error message is a syntax error, but the plugin showed me where exactly it happens).

Second you can't do the dynamic computation you want in Ruby so you have to first build the hash and then pass it as an argument:

Try something along these lines:

```
url = URI.parse("https://example.com/api/send")

files = {}
filepath.each_with_index do |(key, value),index|
  # ... calculate your values
  files["file#{index}"] = UploadIO.new(File.new("./#{key}.#{value}"), "image/jpeg", "#{key}.#{value}")
  # {} will become { "file1" => UploadIO.new(File.new("./image.jpg"), "image/jpeg", "image.jpg") }
end

# "files" hash will be something like this
# {
#   "file1" => UploadIO.new(File.new("./image1.jpg"), "image/jpeg", "image1.jpg"),
#   "file2" => UploadIO.new(File.new("./image2.jpg"), "image/jpeg", "image2.jpg"),
#   "file3" => UploadIO.new(File.new("./image3.jpg"), "image/jpeg", "image3.jpg")
#}
req = Net::HTTP::Put::Multipart.new(url.path, files)

req.basic_auth("username", "password")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = (url.scheme == "https")
res = http.request(req)
```

Comment: Thanks, using Hash did the work. Thank you very much.